# Javascript ES6 Generators

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

I'm diving into javascript generators and I'm really confused.

I'm using `node@0.11.x` to run this example:

```
function find() {
    process.nextTick(function() {  
        it.next(1);
    });
};

var it = (function* main() {
    var k = yield find();

    console.log(k);
})();

it.next();
```

Is there a way to grab the reference to `next` function inside the generator?

Something like:

```
function find(next) {
    process.nextTick(function() {  
        next(1);
    });
};

(function* main() {
    var k = yield find(this.next);

    console.log(k);
})().next();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish, flow-control-wise?

Comment: Something like that. I don't know exactly what, it's my first time playing with it.

Comment: I mean, in your specific example, you could pass `it.next.bind(it)`  if you combine your first and second examples. But there are probably better answers depending on the use-case. But no, a generator can't directly access its `.next` function without capturing the object in the scope.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can't because `this` inside a generator function is not the generator instance, it is the context of the function call. You could do:

```
function find(next) {
    process.nextTick(function() {  
        next(1);
    });
};

var it = (function* main() {
    var k = yield find(it.next.bind(it));

    console.log(k);
})();

it.next();
```

but that's pretty hard to follow. Generally this would be accomplished with a coroutine library like [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co). With that, you would `yield` a promise, and when the promise is resolved, `co` will call `.next` with the value that the promise resolved with.

```
var co = require('co');

function find(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            resolve(1);
        });
    });
}

co(function * (){
    var k = yield find();

    console.log(k);
});
```